# Does a Bangladeshi citizen need a transit visa for an airport layover in Thailand?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, thailand, bangladeshi-citizens, dmk

Thai Lion Air, February 10, Monday 23.50 to 03.20 from Shanghai to DMK (Bangkok Don Mueang Int. Airport), then 19 hours transit, then February 11, 22.00 to 00.25 from DMK to Dhaka (Hazrat Shahjalal Int. Airport).

I'm a Bangladeshi citizen; do I need transit visa if I don't go outside the airport?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need it as you have transit more than 19 hours

All the passengers holding Pakistani, Nepalese, Bangladeshi or Sri Lankan passport traveling via Thailand with transit over 12 hours in Bangkok are now required to get transit visa prior to travel. They may be denied boarding if they don't get a visa prior to travel.

However, the layover in Bangkok is less than 12 hours, there is no requirement of a prior transit visa for these passport holders. They must have a minimum of 6 months of passport validity.

Thus, I recommend you to consult with your travel agent from where you took the ticket. See if you can change flight that has transit hour less than 12 hours.

Best of luck.

Comment: If you stay on the terminal side (do not pass through immigration), you might get away with it. Just sleep at the departing terminal. But no guarantees the airline would let @md mehadi board plane